# Chrome disable web security same origin policy no more working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cors, same-origin-policy

After updating my chrome, I'm unable to disable web security using the `--disable-web-security` command. I've tried lot of options, but without success, including using the `--user-data-dir` flag.

This is the command I'm running:

```
start "" "c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir="d:/_chrome_dev" --disable-web-security
```

I'm getting the following error:

> You are using unsupported command --disable-web-security

Comment: Try `start "" "c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --user-data-dir`

Comment: Also, before you launch chrome, make sure there are no processes already running. Check task manager, and look for `chrome.exe`. Sometimes even when all the windows are closed, it still lingers in the systray for a bit longer.

Comment: Same... "You are using unsupported command --disable-web-security"

Comment: You said "Same". I didn't see any mention of an error "You are using unsupported command". Can you [edit] your question and update it with the error you're receiving?

Comment: Does it show "Stability and security will suffer." after?

Comment: So … build better dev servers instead so you can develop with them with the security settings that a typical user would have.

Comment: I am developing android app in javascript...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this Chrome plugin instead and it wokrs :)
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Answer (score 3):

For mac OS, the steps are as follows:

1 - Close down chrome.  All instances of chrome must be closed first.

2 - Open Terminal

3 - Run the following command:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --disable-web-security --user-data-dir
```

Answer (score 0):

1)You have to make sure there are **no** processes already running. Check task manager, and look for chrome.exe, if exist close it.

2) Then open with command `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -disable-web-security -user-data-dir`